# css overflow hidden can't cover all element?

Tags: css

```css
.powder-box {
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #A5B2B5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px #A5B2B5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.powder-inner {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 #656565;
  background-color: #00c690;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
}

.powder-wave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="powder-box">
  <div class="powder-inner">
    <div class="powder-wave" style="margin-top: -54px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.powder-inner overflow hidden ,there have a border in there . it can't cover all .
how can i cover all ? [there is border there ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s66oE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Update `.powder-inner` class**  using  `border-top-left-radius: 0%;` &  `border-top-right-radius: 0%;` then remove top green curve.

**See output** is browser zoom it and see green curve.

```
.powder-inner {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 49%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 #656565;
    background-color: #00c690;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1px;
    z-index: 2000;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0%;
}
```

```css
.powder-box {
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #A5B2B5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px #A5B2B5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.powder-inner {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 49%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 #656565;
  background-color: #00c690;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
  z-index: 2000;
  border-top-left-radius: 0%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0%;
}

.powder-wave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="powder-box">
  <div class="powder-inner">
    <div class="powder-wave" style="margin-top: -54px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.powder-box {
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #A5B2B5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px #A5B2B5;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: relative;
}

.powder-inner {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 #656565;
  background-color: #00c690;
  overflow:hidden !important;
  margin: 1px;
}

.powder-wave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="powder-box">
  <div class="powder-inner">
    <div class="powder-wave" style=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sady you have to remove your inline style in div have powder-wave class and try again